# Unable to load data from tab delimited to a table using datafactory version 1

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a data in excel which is being converted to tab delimited, and placed in a folder when the pipeline runs, it takes that file and runs. I am having a trouble loading 3 columns data which has all the special character and the error I am having is

> ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
>   given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to
>   type nvarchar of the specified target column.. String or binary data
>   would be
>   truncated.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=The
>   given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to
>   type nvarchar of the specified target.

FYI,  the character length is all okay and within the limit so that is not the issue in here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a lot of in depth searching the excel by loading chunks by chunks I found out what and which cell was causing the issue. There were lot of line breaks in the cell which was causing the issue. Removed all the line breaks and loaded the file. It was successful!

Comment: Thanks for your sharing,you could mark yourself to end this case!